# CosmosDB: Group By + Join

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Been having trouble joining grouped data to the source data. This would be easy with relational SQL, but been spending hours trying to do this with **CosmosDB SQL API** with no success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the **source document**:

```
[
   {
      "stream":{
         "id":"L1",
         "version":1,
         "versionName":"abc1"
      }
   },
   {
      "stream":{
         "id":"L1",
         "version":2,
         "versionName":"abc2"
      }
   },
   {
      "stream":{
         "id":"L2",
         "version":1,
         "versionName":"xyz1"
      }
   },
   {
      "stream":{
         "id":"L2",
         "version":2,
         "versionName":"xyz2"
      }
   },
   {
      "stream":{
         "id":"L2",
         "version":3,
         "versionName":"xyz3"
      }
   }
]
```

Here is the **goal** (grouped by id):

```
[
   {
      "id":"L1",
      "versions":[
         {
            "version":1,
            "versionName":"abc1"
         },
         {
            "version":2,
            "versionName":"abc2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"L2",
      "versions":[
         {
            "version":1,
            "versionName":"xyz1"
         },
         {
            "version":2,
            "versionName":"xyz2"
         },
         {
            "version":3,
            "versionName":"xyz3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I wonder if this is can be done or if it can only be joined together in javascript after the query results are returned?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if this is can be done or if it can only be joined together
>   in javascript after the query results are returned?

I'm afraid this is not supported in cosmos db. The sql of no-sql db is very different from sql of relational db. Aggregating the data into an array is not any one [aggregation method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregates#types-of-aggregate-functions) which means it can't be used with `group by`.

[image]

JOIN is also different. It is used in cosmos db for joining nested array, not for joining horizontal data.

So, i think this could to be implemented with code, sort the data with `order by id`, then loop the results to complete the goal.

Comment: Thanks Jay! I feel I nearly got it working with the SQL api - the query below runs but the versions array is returning an empty array i.e. [] - any ideas?

SELECT d.id, d.versions FROM (
SELECT 
    c.id
     ARRAY(select a.version, a.versionName from a in c.id) as versions
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.stream.id as id
        ,e.stream.version
        ,e.stream.versionName
    FROM e
    ) c
GROUP BY c.id
) d